# Rocks detection , i cant detect all of rocks

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, image-processing

I do not know how go detect all of rock. i can detect some rock. Some rock is black i cant detect.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
def nothing(x):
    pass
H_Max= 169
H_Min=147
S_Max=103
S_Min=19
V_Max=199
V_Min=139

while True:
    name_pic='153.jpg'
    img = cv2.imread(name_pic)
    frame = cv2.imread(name_pic)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (1500, 1000))
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (1500, 1000))
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (5, 5), 0)
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(blurred, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, (H_Min, S_Min, V_Min), (H_Max, S_Max, V_Max))
    kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)

    frame_out, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(
    mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    for cnt in contours:
        M = cv2.moments(cnt)
        if M['m00'] == 0 :
            M['m00'] = 0.1
    cx = int(M['m10'] / M['m00'])
    cy = int(M['m01'] / M['m00'])
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    if area < 2.5 :
        continue
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
    cv2.imshow('frame1',frame)
    cv2.imshow('fimg', img)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if key == 27:
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I do not know how to improve my detection.

Thank you

This is picture before and after processing.

Before detection:

[image]

After detection:

[image]

Comment: I would try HSV solution. You can select a color within a range and then keep/remove it. I will try to do something but I can't guarantee any result. Did you applied any kind of preprocessing on first image ?

Comment: This is first image 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zgddlcgqt5rvcgq/153.jpg?dl=0

Comment: I am working on it right now..BTW, how many rocks do you plan to detect ? I don't know if you can find all of them because of some false positives..

Comment: Nothing, I can't achieve a more acceptable result..

Comment: i want to detect size of stone more than 15 cm